# Neo4J conditional formatting of a string attribute from a set of boolean attributes

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a node with the following attributes :

```
MyNode
  stage_1: boolean
  stage_2: boolean
  stage_3: boolean
```

I'd like to create a query that generate a `macro_step` string attribute, that is conditionnally filled by the values of the booleans. For instance, if `stage_1` and `stage_3` were true but `stage_2`false, I would like MyNode.macro_steps to be filled with `"STAGE_1 STAGE2"`

I tried the following but it doesn't work :

```
match (mo:MyNode)
mo.macro_steps = ""
case
  when mo.stage_1 then mo.macro_steps += "STAGE_1\n"
  when mo.stage_2 then mo.macro_steps += "STAGE_2\n"
  // etc.
  else null
end
return mo
```

How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
MATCH (n:MyNode)
WITH n, 
reduce(str = '', propertyKey IN keys(properties(n)) | 
CASE WHEN n[propertyKey] = true THEN str + toUpper(propertyKey) + " " 
     WHEN n[propertyKey] = false THEN str + toUpper(replace(propertyKey, '_', '')) + " " 
     ELSE str END) AS macro_steps
SET n.macro_steps = trim(macro_steps)
RETURN n
```

For the node, created by:

```
MERGE (r:MyNode{sample_1: true, sample_2: true, sample_3: false})
```

The first query gives:

```
╒══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╕
│"n"                                                                   │
╞══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╡
│{"sample_1":true,"sample_2":true,"sample_3":false,"macro_steps":"SAMPL│
│E_1 SAMPLE_2 SAMPLE3"}                                                │
└──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

As suggested by @nimrodserok, in the comments, if you only want `true` valued property keys, then this is the query:

```
MATCH (n:MyNode) 
WITH n,  reduce(str = '', propertyKey IN keys(properties(n)) |  
CASE WHEN n[propertyKey] = true THEN str + toUpper(propertyKey) + ' '
     ELSE str END) AS macro_steps 
SET n.macro_steps = trim(macro_steps) 
RETURN n
```

The output is:

```
{"stage_1":true,"stage_2":false,"stage_3":true,"macro_steps":"STAGE_1 STAGE_3"}
```

Comment: I think you mean: `MATCH (n:MyNode)
WITH n, 
reduce(str = '', propertyKey IN keys(properties(n)) | 
CASE WHEN n[propertyKey] = true THEN str + toUpper(propertyKey) + ' ' 
     WHEN n[propertyKey] = false THEN str
     ELSE str END) AS macro_steps
SET n.macro_steps = trim(macro_steps)
RETURN n`

Comment: which_gives: `{"stage_1":true,"stage_2":false,"stage_3":true,"macro_steps":"STAGE_1 STAGE_3"}`

Comment: Thanks, @nimrodserok for the suggestion, I missed the `toUpper` part, I am still not clear about how false values are to be handled.

Comment: I think `macro_steps` should only contain the `true` properties, so I adjusted your answer a bit...

Comment: That's most likely the case. I have added your query as well in the answer, with one minor tweak.